# Fix smoke simulation in an animation

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

How can I fix this when trying to simulate fire+smoke in a dancing character?
It looks like there are 5 arms, is there a way to create a smoother simulation when movement of the emitter is involved?

[image]

Comment: you should write what you want to have...or have two images: what you have and what you wanna have. Else we are just guessing ....

Comment: lol my bad, completly forgot that part. I want like only one arm, it looks like there are 5 different arms because of that fire. Idk if thats just how fire works or with there is a work around to create a more smooth simulation.

Comment: Increase Sampling Substeps for character simulation ... https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/physics/fluid/type/flow.html?highlight=sampling%20substeps

Comment: @vklidu is right. What’s happening here is that you are finding out the smoke simulation, like animation, is in discreet time steps: it is not continuous. Make the time steps smaller by adding more substeps (aka steps per frame), and it looks *more* continuous.

Comment: thanks u guys!!